# Is there a limit for the number of relative/dependent clauses in a sentence?

Tags: gerunds, relative-clauses, dependent-clause

I need to correct the following sentence:

> The article is proving the thesis of shame as a feeling that functions
> as a bond between people, by presenting a historical analysis of this
> feeling in three different sections, relying on texts of different
> eras such as the *Iliad*, *The Confessions*, and *The Truce*, in which the
> author tries to answer several other questions.

I have always suggested students to try to put just one dependent/relative clause in a sentence in order to avoid this ladder effect in which you subordinate clauses ad infinitum. I was wondering if there is an actual rule as to the number of dependent/relative clauses you are allowed to put in a sentence. The use of repeated gerunds, by the way, is certainly a constant when "listing" clauses.

Comment: I don't think there is any rule (some authors write very long sentences), but in this case it's unclear what _which_ in the final clause refers to. Obviously not 'texts... such as _The Iliad_'.

Comment: Consider the old nursery rhyme [The House that Jack Built](https://sites.pitt.edu/~dash/type2035.html)

Comment: There is no limit to right-branching subordination -- relative clauses like Jack's house and complement clauses like "he said that she said" both branch rightward and can go on indefinitely, as long as all the lexical and syntactic ducks line up. But there are definitely limits to other types of clause embedding. For instance, *_The horse the man my brother knew purchased died_ obeys all the structural rules but runs afoul of the center-embedding prohibition.

Comment: Grammaticality-wise, no. But surely Orwell's Sixth (avoid the outlandish) and Grice's maxim of manner (subsection _KISS_: avoid over-complicating) are equally binding.

Comment: ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)